# Adding Custom Web Assets for FullCalendar (Symfony / EasyAdmin)

Tags: symfony, fullcalendar, easyadmin

Symfony : 6.1.4
EasyAdmin : 4.3.5

According to the [documentation](https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/design.html#adding-custom-web-assets) for adding Custom Web Assets :

> Use the configureAssets() method in the dashboard and/or the CRUD controllers to add your own CSS and JavaScript files

So I want to add the FullCalendar assets.

```
class DashboardController extends AbstractDashboardController
{

//... 
   public function configureAssets(): Assets
    {
        return parent::configureAssets()
            ->addWebpackEncoreEntry('admin')
            ->addCssFile('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.11.3/main.min.css')
            ->addJsFile('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.11.3/main.min.js');

    }

//...

 #[Route('/admin', name: 'admin')]
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('admin/index.html.twig');
    }

}
```

*admin/index.html.twig :*

```
// ...
{% block main %}
    <div id="booking"></div>

{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}

    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('booking');
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
locale: 'fr',
buttonText: {
today: 'Aujourd\'hui',
month: 'Mois',
week: 'Semaine'
},
timeZone: 'Europe/Paris',
headerToolbar: {
start: 'prev,next today',
center: 'title',
end: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek'
},
events: {{ data|raw }},
navLinks: true

});
calendar.render();
});
    </script>


{% endblock %}
```

But the calendar is not displayed.

No errors in my browser console.

Comment: Any errors in your browser console? Did you check the network tool in the browser to see if the js and css files are loaded successfully? From your description it doesn't sound like you've done any basic checks or debugging at all yet.

Comment: I have many mistakes in my browser console but I don't understand why they prevent my code from working. GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/build/admin.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
main.min.js:6 FullCalendar VDOM already loaded
(anonyme) @ main.min.js:6
(anonyme) @ main.min.js:6
admin:28          GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/build/runtime.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: None of those appear directly related to fullCalendar except the VDOM warning (which is odd, because it suggests you might be trying to load fullCalendar more than once in your page). However you do clearly have problems where your page is trying to load files which don't exist, and that might be giving you javascript-related problems more widely.

Comment: I fixed the problem of double loading of FullCalendar and the one about loading non-existent files. I have no more errors in my console. But still nothing. Weird.

Comment: In that case you need to investigate more closely. Use the element inspector and the Javascript debugger. Does the "booking" element exist in the page in your browser? Is there anything inside it (which might have been added by fullCalendar)? Does the script block where you wrote the fullCalendar code exist in the page in your browser? If so, try and debug it with the JS debugger to see if it actually gets executed.